# RSpec added midway - how to generate stubs of all existing resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I added RSpec mid way and want to have RSpec create all the stub test cases for the existing resources. Any quick way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rails generate <type> <name> -s
```

If its a scaffold, you need to temporarily remove the migration so as to fool the generator, and then answer "no".

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
rails generate scaffold <model_name>
```

and answer "no" when asked to overwrite existing files. It might be less stressful emotionally to do this in a new project and then copy over the generated spec files.